# React SSR with styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering

I have a problem when using React SSR with style-component. I have an SSR code that requires a component that bundled with Webpack and Babel and renders it to a string but sheet.getStyleTags() of styled-component always return empty string. Does anyone know how to fix it

```
    const App = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/server/${pageName}.bundle.js`).default;

    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const content = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(<App />));
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags();
```